# Chinese characters in mailto subject line of email

Tags: html, encoding, html-encode

I'm looking to add some Chinese characters in a mailto: email link.

I've tried

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=调查 / Inquiry">Email</a>
```

but when I click on the link the Outlook subject line shows:

> è°ƒæŸ¥äº¨å¾·æ£® / Inquiry

I've also tried

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=&#35843;&#26597; / Inquiry">Email</a>
```

but I get the same result as above.

I realize this may be an Outlook issue but I'm interested in finding out the correct way to implement this functionality.

Comment: What encoding do you use in your document?

Comment: http://www.mandarintools.com/email.html :) Encoding in emails is hard to do since it depends too much on the client the end user has. Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: "this may be an Outlook issue but I'm interested in finding out the correct way to implement this functionality" - you already have the correct way. There is no obvious way to implement a workaround for broken browsers, OSes and e-mail clients. The problem may not even be Outlook - perhaps the link is already broken when it reaches Outlook from the browser.

Answer (score 3):

**Raw URL Encode**

To encode mailto links / standard links with special characters you can use the [php function rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

If you are looking for an online tool try http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/rawurlencode

Using your example:

`<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=调查 / Inquiry">Email</a>`

would convert to:

`<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=%E8%B0%83%E6%9F%A5 / Inquiry">Email</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Since subject is in mail header, there is no way to know what encoding you are using. You need to use MIME Mail header extension defined in this RFC,

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt

The subject in Chinese would look like this,

```
Subject: =?GB2312?B?u7bTrbLOvNPDwLn61bm74Q==?=
```

But more and more clients assume UTF-8 encoding now. You might want try that also.

Comment: Changing to mailto: link to something like =?GB2312?B?u7bTrbLOvNPDwLn61bm74Q==?= will not solve the problem, it will just make the e-mail client encode the string "=?GB2312?B?u7bTrbLOvNPDwLn61bm74Q==?=" using the relevant transport encoding. The problem here is Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

It's cumbersome but possible, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2007/02/12/International-Mailto-URIs-in-IE7.aspx) is a good article that discusses both the standard compliant way of an ideal world and real world scenarios with  Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

For your text in comment #1, please enable the "Tool->options->mail format->International Options"->"Enable UTF-8 support for mailto: protocol"

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to put non-ASCII characters in subject lines for a while now. The bottom line is: it does not work reliably.

My (limited) understanding of *why* it does not work is that the standards say that email is 7-bit ASCII. The MIME standard gets around that by encoding the contents of the email differently. However: the subject line is not part of the contents. It's a header.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default charset of outlook is gb2312, so when you encode the subject, you must translate the Chinese character to gb2313, then encode it.
In a word, the charset which you pass must be consistent with the default charset of outlook.